# My prefix gets you places, my infix is a companion,

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix gets you places
>
> My infix is a companion
>
> And my suffix are unwanted plants

This one shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> carpetweed
>  car takes you places
>  a pet is a companion
>  weed is an unwanted plant

Comment: I didn't even know that was a plant...

Comment: The suffix or the solution?